# Retrieve facet labels from a ggplot or a gtable/gTree/grob/gDesc object

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, facet-grid

I have data I'm plotting using `ggplot`'s `facet_grid`:

My data:

```
species <- c("spcies1","species2")
conditions <- c("cond1","cond2","cond3")
batches <- 1:6

df <- expand.grid(species=species,condition=conditions,batch=batches)

set.seed(1)
df$y <- rnorm(nrow(df))
df$replicate <- 1
df$col.fill <- paste(df$species,df$condition,df$batch,sep=".")
```

My plot:

```
integerBreaks <- function(n = 5, ...)
{
  library(scales)
  breaker <- pretty_breaks(n, ...)
  function(x){
    breaks <- breaker(x)
    breaks[breaks == floor(breaks)]
  }
}

library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df,aes(x=replicate,y=y,color=col.fill))+
  geom_point(size=3)+facet_grid(~col.fill,scales="free_x")+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=integerBreaks())+
  theme_minimal()+theme(legend.position="none",axis.title=element_text(size=8))
```

which gives:
[image]

Obviously the labels are long and come out pretty messed up in the figure so I was wondering if there's a way edit these labels in the `ggplot` object (`p`) or the `gtable`/`gTree`/`grob`/`gDesc` object (`ggplotGrob(p)`).

I am aware that one way of getting better labels is to use the [`labeller function`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labeller.html) when the `ggplot` object is created but in my case I'm specifically looking for a way to edit the facet labels after the `ggplot` object has been created.

Comment: What do you want them to change them to? The labels are nested quite deeply within the `gtable` that `ggplotGrob(p)` produces

Comment: I'd like them to be: gsub("cond","c",df$condition)

Comment: Ah I see and this is presumably why you don't just use that variable in the facetting? B/c you want them to still be their own facets?

Comment: Yeah, that's more or less the case. It's part of a longer code that tests after the ggplot has been created if it can edit the facet labels based on certain conditions, which happen to be met in this example. Again, I know that SO has a few posts on how to create labels during the generation of the ggplot object but in my case it would make things much easier if it's possible to edit the labels in the ggplot or ggplotGrob(p) objects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the facet names are nested quite deeply within the `gtable` that `ggplotGrob()` gives you. However, this is still possible and since the OP explicitly wants to edit them after being plotted, you can do this with:

```
library(grid)
gg <- ggplotGrob(p)

edited_grobs <- mapply(FUN = function(x, y) {
                                  x[["grobs"]][[1]][["children"]][[2]][["children"]][[1]][["label"]] <- y
                                  return(x)
                              },
                        gg$grobs[which(grepl("strip-t",gg$layout$name))],
                        unique(gsub("cond","c", df$condition)),
                        SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

gg$grobs[which(grepl("strip-t",gg$layout$name))] <- edited_grobs
grid.draw(gg)
```

[image]

Note that this extracts all the strips using `gg$grobs[which(grepl("strip-t",gg$layout$name))]` and passes them to the `mapply` to be reset with the `gsub(...)` that OP specified in their comment.

In general, if you want to access just one of the text labels, there is a very similar structure which I made use of in my `mapply`:

```
num_to_access <- 1
gg$grobs[which(grepl("strip-t",gg$layout$name))][[num_to_access]][["grobs"]][[1]][["children"]][[2]][["children"]][[1]]$label
```

So to access the 4th label for example all you would need to do is change `num_to_acces` to be 4. Hope this helps!